# Python/Ruby: cronjob wont load ruby gems?

Tags: python, ruby, rubygems, subprocess, cron-task

How do you run a ruby script in cron and get it to load all the 'require' gems?  I am kicking off this ruby script as a subprocess in python:

```
!#/usr/bin/env python
 ...
def ruby_importdb(import_this):
  if formatinput == 'nessus':
    print '[+] importing the report to the database'
    subprocess.Popen(["/usr/local/rvm/rubies/default/bin/ruby /scripts/nessus-xml2db.rb " + import_this],
                          shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
```

cronjob is as follows:

`51 11 * * * /scripts/nessus-export-scans-nes.py 2>&1  | logger`

Events in /var/log/messages show the following error when the python script trys to execute the ruby subprocess function:

```
root: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in require': cannot load such file -- mysql (LoadError)
root: #011from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in require'
root: #011from /scripts/nessus-report-database/nessus-xml2db.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

The code works find if I run this script from my user account or root.

Answer (score 0):

adding the following lines to crontab solved this issue:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
BASH_ENV=/root/.bashrc
```

and adding the following line to .bashrc:

`source /usr/local/rvm/environments/default`

which contains the following environment variables:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin:$PATH"
export GEM_HOME='/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1'
export GEM_PATH='/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global'
export MY_RUBY_HOME='/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1'
export IRBRC='/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/.irbrc'
unset MAGLEV_HOME
unset RBXOPT
export RUBY_VERSION='ruby-2.2.1'
```